# Why do user-defined string literals and integer literals have different behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I'm learning about user-defined literals, and confused with the following test code:

```
std::chrono::seconds operator"" _s(unsigned long long s) {
    return std::chrono::seconds(s);
}

std::string operator"" _str(const char *s, std::size_t len) {
    return std::string(s, len);
}

int main() {
    auto str = "xxxxx"_str;
    std::cout << str.size() << std::endl;    // works

    auto sec = 4_s;
    std::cout << sec.count() << std::endl;   // works

    std::cout << "xxxxx"_str.size() << std::endl;   // works

    std::cout << 4_s.count() << std::endl;   // does **NOT** work!

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

> error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""_s.count' with argument of type 'unsigned long long' or 'const char *', and no matching literal operator template
>        cout << 4_s.count() << endl;

It seems that it takes ***_s.count*** as a user-defined literal. Also, a floating-point literal behaves like an integer literal.

Why do user-defined integer literals and string literals have different behavior?

Comment: what about (4_s).count?

Comment: `(4_s).count` works. You CANNOT have `(` or `)` in the `ud-suffix`.

Comment: @for_stack It seems weird, `.` could not be used in `ud-suffix` either; can't get why `_s.count` is parsed as the whole `ud-suffix`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Good to see you. It's not weird if an explanation can be found.

Comment: `4_s.count` is parsed as a [preprocessing number](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ppnumber#nt:pp-number) token, which is tolerated by the preprocessor and is [converted to a token](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.7.sentence-2) after preprocessing but before syntactic and semantic analysis, but it can't be converted to a valid token (e.g. interger literal or floating literal), and thus violates [\[lex.pptoken\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#1). Admittedly the compiler error is totally unhelpful in this case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**That's how *floating point* literals work!!**

Add a pair of parentheses and it should work:

```
std::cout << (4_s).count();
```

Or alternatively, separate them (to stop the compiler from interpreting it as an ill-formed fractional constant floating point literal):

```
std::cout << 4_s .count();
//              ^ Space here!
```

Reference: [CppReference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Notes)

In the ***Notes*** section of the reference above,

> Due to maximal munch, user-defined integer and floating point literals ending in [`p`, `P`, (since C++17)] `e` and `E`, when followed by the operators `+` or `-`, **must be separated from the operator with whitespace** in the source:
>
> ```
> long double operator""_E(long double);
> long double operator""_a(long double);
> int operator""_p(unsigned long long);
>
> auto x = 1.0_E+2.0;  // error
> auto y = 1.0_a+2.0;  // OK
> auto z = 1.0_E +2.0; // OK
> auto w = 1_p+2;      // error
> auto u = 1_p +2;     // OK
> ```

So when it comes to dot, which is used as **decimal point**, it must be separated from anything behind, or it'll be treated as **part of the floating point number**.

I have tested the example above from CppReference and got a *very* similar error message:

```
test.cpp:19:10: error: unable to find numeric literal
operator 'operator""_E+2.0'
                    ^^^^^^
 auto x = 1.0_E+2.0;  // error
```

Got the point how `_E+2.0` is considered as a whole *ud-suffix*?

---

My original explanation attempt can be found in the [revision history](/revisions/47467463/4) of this post.

Comment: This question isn't about *how* to make it work; it's about *why* it doesn't work. Apparently, there's a difference in precedence when using strings versus integers, but I believe that a good answer to the question should explain why the language is designed that way.

Comment: You beat me in adding the link to the `CppReference` page. I was reading it before you posted & updated your answer.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I added it even ***after*** I had read it all :)

Comment: I've learned over time that `CppReference` is truly an excellent resource & repository that acts as a great lookup table or guide. Trying to get any helpful information from MS well that's a whole different story...

Comment: All compilers shows the same error btw. So it is probably not a bug.

Comment: @Zefick What is ***all***?

Comment: @iBug VC++, GCC, clang. And funny thing here is that you cannot define `operator""_s.count` even if you want.